# CSS validation failure: "Value Error : background-image no-repeat is not a background-image value"

Tags: html, css

I am validating my CSS on w3c.org and am receiving the following error message:

`Value Error : background-image no-repeat is not a background-image value : url(http://d20m4dvzhiuv61.cloudfront.net/assets/bg-body-3a1d6e7921cb2e11584ad84371a73188.jpg),no-repeat`

What does this mean?

Comment: change it to `background-image:url(xxx)` `background-repeat:no-repeat` two different properties or use `background:url(xxx) no-repeat;`